# XDocument replace all node value with lower case

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to make all values within an XDocument lower case. What's the best way of doing this?

To clarify, I want to change ALL text values, without specifying the names of any nodes.

Answer (score 7):

You could also do something like:

```
doc.Document
   .DescendantNodes()
   .OfType<XText>()
   .ToList().ForEach(x => x.Value = x.Value.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it with XPath:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

foreach (XText text in (IEnumerable)xdoc.XPathEvaluate("//*/text()"))
{
     text.Value = text.Value.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: I have added the "right" using, because `XPathEvaluate` is an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Can change even the attribute text, with an example of XML...

```
string @xml = @"<X:NOTE xmlns:X='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<TO>TOVE</TO>
<FROM>JANI</FROM>
<HEADING>REMINDER</HEADING>
<BODY>DON'T FORGET ME THIS WEEKEND!</BODY>
</X:NOTE>";

var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var nodes = xml2.DescendantNodes();

foreach (XNode node in nodes)
{
    XText text = node as XText;

    if (text != null)
    {
        text.Value = text.Value.ToLower();
    }
    else
    {
        // This part if you want to ToLower attributes' values
        XElement element = node as XElement;

        if (element != null)
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attr in element.Attributes())
            {
                attr.Value = attr.Value.ToLower();
            }
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(xml2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below sample will sort it out the issue

```
strxml =" <cars><name><ford>model1</ford>TEXTVALUE<renault>MODEL2</renault></name></cars>"

   XDocument objDocument = XDocument.Parse(strxml);        

   var varNodeType = objDocument.
                     DescendantNodes().
                     Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);

   foreach (var objSubType in varNodeType)
   {
     ((System.Xml.Linq.XText)(objSubType)).Value = ((System.Xml.Linq.XText)(objSubType)).Value.ToLower();
   }
```